# How to change the name of the image?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, image-processing, angularjs-directive

Angularjs

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};
}]);

app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.uploadFileAndFieldsToUrl = function(file, fields, uploadUrl){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    console.log(file) //File { name: "franklindroosevelt1.jpg", lastModified: 1522139208000, lastModifiedDate: Date 2018-03-27T08:26:48.000Z, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 63159, type: "image/jpeg" }
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        fd.append(fields[i].name, fields[i].data)

    }
    console.log(file)//File { name: "franklindroosevelt1.jpg", lastModified: 1522139208000, lastModifiedDate: Date 2018-03-27T08:26:48.000Z, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 63159, type: "image/jpeg" }
    $http.post(Appname+"/upload_image/", fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(){
    })
    .error(function(){
    });
}
}]);


app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

$scope.$watch('myFile', function(newFileObj){
    if(newFileObj)
        $scope.filename = newFileObj.name;
});

$scope.uploadForm = function(){
    var file = $scope.myFile;
    var uploadUrl = "/formUpload";
    var fields = [{"name": "filename", "data": $scope.filename}];
    fileUpload.uploadFileAndFieldsToUrl(file, fields, uploadUrl);
};

}]);
```

HTML

```
 <div class="maincontent">
     <div ng-app="Appschedule" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container container1">
        <p>
            <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>File Name:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="filename"></input>
        </p>
        <button ng-click="uploadForm()">upload me</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

I had written a code  to upload a image into directory , here i want to change the image name based on input text or any random name.I cant change the name , the name remains same while uploading. Is there any other way to send the name. please help me

Comment: use `fd.append(fields[i].name, new Date().getTime()+'_'+fields[i].name)` instead of `fd.append(fields[i].name, fields[i].data)`. and check in fd variable after loop `console.log(fd)`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way to send the name?

Here is code showing how to send name as string and file in the same request:

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);

        var info = {
            "text":"file_name"
        };
        fd.append('data', angular.toJson(info));

        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
             transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })

        .success(function(){
        })

        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);
```

On server side it's in `req.body.data`, so it can be received i.e. like this:

```
upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        res.json({error_code: 1, err_desc: err});
        return;
    }

    console.log(req.body.data);

    res.json({error_code: 0, err_desc: null});
})
```